# Why we need Pointers for assigning a value to a variable in Go/C but not C#/Java

Tags: c#, pointers, go

It's a actually a general question, but it occurred now that I'm working with Go and C#.
Say we want to assign a variable from user's input in Go:

```
func main() {
    var input float64
    fmt.Scan(&input)
}
```

It's pretty much clear why we need a memory location to put our new value in. But why in languages like Java or C#, we are not following the same logic:

```
var input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
// and not &input ...
```

Comment: That's a statement not a question. Reference vs value is just more abstracted in C# and Java. I don't personally find it to be a good thing. In your example you don't need a reference to do assignment, you have to pass by reference to `Scan` because that's how it's designed. It couldn't be be by value in any language so in C# since types like int are always value types, it would probably return the value or use an out param.

Comment: Huh, the stuff in answers about how objects are born references in C#/Java but not in Go is true, but this example doesn't really involve it, necessarily. You can read a string with `(*bufio.Reader).ReadString`, convert it to an int with `strconv.Atoi`, and assign it to a variable in Go too, though `Scan` is shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java and C# are higher level languages which abstract most of the memory management and other particular things required in lower level languages like C.

In this case, the `Console.ReadLine()` function allocates memory to store the console input and copies it to the `input` variable.

Since these languages have garbage collection, allocating and deallocating memory is done automatically, so the framework don't require you to explicitly pass a memory address to write to, and doesn't expect you to free the memory when you are done using it.

**Edit:**

See @kostix comment for a great improvement to this answer.

Comment: Go has garbage collection as well as C# and Java. The crucial point of difference between Go and those oher languages is that the designers of Go strive hard to make it have as little *magic* as possible. One reason for this is enabling the programmer to easily estimate the runtime costs just by looking at the code. Another one is lowering the "WTF factor": say, no braindead "value types vs refernce types" distinction -- everything is a value and passed by value, so what you pass is what you get ;-) Pointers are values, too, and you use them when you need them.

Comment: In Java and C#, you use object references most of the time, which contain a pointer even you don't know it. In C#, you can use a `struct` if you don't want your type to implicitly get object-passed-by-reference semantics. In Go, you *always* start with a `struct` or other non-pointer type, and only get pointers when they're asked for using `*`/`&`/`new` or implied by something else you do (e.g., slices, strings, maps and `func` and `interface` values are implemented with pointers).

Answer (score 1):

In Go, like C/C++, pointer variables are how types can be passed by reference.

Languages like Java and C# discourage the use of pointer variables. C# has the "ref" keyword and "boxing" for passing value types by reference.

See here for more on "ref": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx
See here for more on "boxing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Comment: Also, C# has IntPtr and Marshal namespace.

Comment: Java also have boxing and unboxing. (int vs Integer if I remember correctly)